# Match similar special character in filters

Tags: oracle, collation, string-searching

I have to perform a search on a table with Turkish city names.

The users would enter the first 4 characters of a city and I need to fetch the results from SQL.

For example, user wants to find the entries for `Istanbul`, so he would enter `ista` or `Ista` or `ISTA`

Problem is that `Istanbul` is written with special character. It is `Ìstanbùl`. So my query

`where UPPER(city) like 'UPPER(<entered value>)%'`

will not find it. It only finds it when the user enters `Ìsta`  (with the special character).

Is there a way of converting similar special character to 1 character. So for example `ìíî` will be converted to `i`. This way a user can find `Ìnstanbùl` with whatever variant of `i` they enter.

Comment: I'm not sure if the special character would count as an "accent", but you could check the collation on your database, and see if it's accent-insensitive. This would not convert values to something else, but, would treat them (in terms of searches and character matching) as identical; just like a case-insensitive collation would allow a search for `'I%'` to match both `Indiana` and `ice cream`.

Comment: I found the answer to my problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689157/compare-strings-ignoring-accents-in-sql-oracle
using the nlssort function

Answer (score 0):

The replace function will find a character in a string and replace it. 
Use:
REPLACE(str, find_string, replace_with)

in your case:
where UPPER(REPLACE(city, 'Ì', 'I') like 'UPPER()%'

Hope this helps

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php

Comment: That would mean, I have to know and replace every special character that could be used. I 'm hoping there is a more simpler/easier solution.

Comment: If you query the database with a hardcoded value including a special character do you get the same result as a user-entered one?